# In Windows 8 will it be possible to use WCF in conjunction with HTML5/JS?

Tags: .net, html5, wcf, windows-8

Correct me if I'm wrong but I've heard that communicating with a database in Windows 8 will more than likely be done with WCF when working with C#/XAML.

If this is true then will this also be the case when working with HTML5/JS?

Answer (score 3):

On December 14th, 2011, Microsoft MVP [Morten Nielsen said](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/01896385-c75a-4c13-895b-ff4c653cd799):

> You can use HttpClient to download pretty much anything from the web. 
>   Why don't you configure your WCF service to return data as JSON, and
>   use the DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize the results?

In an HTML5/JS application, the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class obviously won't be available, but the balance of his advice still applies.

---

**TL;DR**

- Configure your WCF service to return data as JSON.
- And use a Javascript library such as [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on the client-side to communicate with your WCF service.

---

Emphasis: Microsoft *may* provide helper Javascript libraries to communicate with WCF services, but don't hold your breath. [Heck, they've already ruffled a few feathers by [dropping the System.Data namespace for XAML apps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8689442/109941).]

Until you hear otherwise, use a popular Javascript library to make it happen on the client-side.